# How to print user UID's and groups that a user is a member of?

Tags: python, flags, uid

How do I print a user's UID going off of this section of code? I am trying to flag UIDs with more than one user name associated with them. Flag GIDs with more than one group name 
associated with them, but am unable to display user's UIDS

```py
import grp
groups = grp.getgrall()
for group in groups:
    for user in group[3]:
        print (user, group[0])
```

When I add `os.getuid` I get an error for syntax

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getuid()
1000
>>> os.getgroups()
[4, 20, 24, 27, 30, 46, 107, 110, 1000]
```

Did you forget to `import os` by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this isn't exactly what you want, but I am fairly certain you are looking for the sister library to `grp` which is `pwd`.

```
import grp
import pwd

for group in grp.getgrall():
    for user_name in group.gr_mem:
        user = pwd.getpwnam(user_name)
        print(group.gr_name, group.gr_gid, user_name, user.pw_uid)
```